# How to skip to next url if element is not found or if timeoutexception occured in selenium wait until function

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling, timeoutexception

I am trying to scrape the daily observation table from a weather site. I have the code below for getting the specific table:

```
#Iterate request to each weather station and date
for station,month,year in product(weather_station,month,year): 
    
    areacode = weather_station[station]['areacode']
    
    #Set link according to data need
    driver.get('https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/'+countrycode+'/'+station+'/'+areacode+'/date/'+str(year)+'-'+str(month))
    
    #Wait webpage to fully load necessary tables
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    
    #Update xpath incase webpage html format changes
    xpath_html_loc='//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table'
    tables = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)))
    
    #Save only the necessary table from loaded webpage
    for table in tables:
        histo_table = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
        histo_weather = histo_table[2].fillna('')
        
    print("Weather observations for ",str(month), "-", str(year)," from station",station, "is ready \n")
```

This code iterates across all the necessary pages from site and works fine when getting the specific table I want but when the table is not present from the page or the link is unavailable it returns this error: [timeoutexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CneaQ.png)

I read about try and except option but I can't seem to make it work in this case. Can you suggest with a better working solution? The code below with try and except still outputs the timeoutexception error. I want to have a code where it skips the current url and goes to the next one (i.e. returns to the start of the for loop to iterate the next) if the table element is not present or the link is unavailable.

```
try:
    #Set link according to data need
    driver.get('https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/'+countrycode+'/'+station+'/'+areacode+'/date/'+str(year)+'-'+str(month))

    #Wait webpage to fully load necessary tables
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

    #Update xpath incase webpage html format changes
    xpath_html_loc='//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table'
    tables = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)
    print(tables)
except TimeoutException as exception:
    raise exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to achieve the same.

```
if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc))>0:
     //Do something
else:
    //Do something
```

updating the code with complete solution.

```
#Set link according to data need
driver.get('https://www.wunderground.com/weather/us/pa/indiana/date/2020-09')

#Wait webpage to fully load necessary tables
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//lib-city-header//lib-subnav//div[@class='subnav-contain']//span[contains(text(),'History')]")))
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//lib-city-header//lib-subnav//div[@class='subnav-contain']//span[contains(text(),'History')]").click()
tables = 0;
try:
    xpath_html_loc='//lib-city-history-observation//table'
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)))
    tables = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)
    print(len(tables))
except TimeoutException as exception:
    pass

if tables > 0:
    print('IF')
else:
    print('Else')
```

Comment: Nice and simple workaround, this works for the driver.find_elements. However if I use this for the wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)), i get a timeout error (similiar to the photo attached). it does not reach the if part of the code since the error gets read at the wait.until line of code. how do i get it to work? the simple driver.find_elements does not get me the tables I need so I have to use the wait.until so that the page is fully loaded

Comment: Why you have used `raise exception`? any specific reason?

Comment: no specific reason. i just tried if it will remove/skip the timeout exception but it didn't. I was able to find a workaround to my problem. see the answer i posted. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have a workaround using below:

```
for link in links
    try:
        print("Trying for ",link)
        #Set link according to data need
        driver.get(link)
        #Wait webpage to fully load necessary tables
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

        #Update xpath incase webpage html format changes
        xpath_html_loc='//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table'
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)))
        tables = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_html_loc)
    except:
        # If the loading took too long, print message
        print("Loading took too long! Data unavailable")
        continue
    
    if(len(tables)>0:
        #Do code here
    else:
       print("data is unavailable")
       continue
```

The loop continues even if the link is unavailable or if the table cannot be loaded because of the try and except code (this avoids the timeout exception). I used both wait.until expected condition (to fully load the webpage and the table i need) and the find_elements (to locate the specific table). The if-else code suggested by @Dilip below continues the for loop if the table cannot be found in the page or if it is really not available even after loading the webpage.

Thanks for all your help!